# UITextField from UISearchBar in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am accessing textfield of searchbar . This keeps changing

For iOS 6 i am using

```
    textField = [searchbar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
```

It changed in iOS 7 there is a view and in that there was a subview from which we can get textField , So i am using following code for iOS 7 or greater iOS

```
    UIView *searchbarview = [searchbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"searchbarview.subviews Array is %@",searchbarview.subviews.description);
    textField = (UITextField *)[searchbarview.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
```

Now since iOS 7.1 the searchbarview has only one subview which is UISearchBarBackground unlike iOS 7.0 where it has two subviews, So i am not able to get textField even if i iterate through all the subviews using a for loop

Can anyone help me with this
Thanks,

**EDIT**
Here is the log of array returned by  searchbarview.subviews , you can see it returns only 1 object which is UISearchBarBackground , so i am wondering where is UITextField object

```
searchbarview.subviews Array is (
"<UISearchBarBackground: 0xe6bc9d0; frame = (0 0; 768 50); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xe6bcb20>>"
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to access the UITextField?

Comment: I want to change text alignment of textfield

Comment: Could you log subviews of `UISearchBarBackground` object?

Comment: You can try your code in `viewWillAppear`! Maybe textField-object is not allocated yet until searchbar is showed. I tried my code after I create UISearchBar and I catch problem like you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tested on simulator of iOS 7.1. I see structure of UISearchBar like this:

===============================================

**UISearchBar**

++ UIView

++++ UISearchBarBackground

++++ **UISearchBarTextField** (This is UITextField object)

++++++++ _UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView

++++++++ UIImageView

===============================================

[image: take from Spark Inspector]

So on **iOS 7.1**, you can get UITextField like this:

```
UIView *subviews = [searchbar.subviews lastObject];
UITextField *textView = (id)[subviews.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
```

===============================================

**UPDATE**

If your `UISearchBar` is in a `UIViewController`, try your code in method `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`!

**Don't look for `UITextField` as soon as you create `UISearchBar`** (look for after `UISearchBar` has already appeared on screen)

Comment: Thanks for the answer here subviews.subview yields me array with 1 view and that is UISearchBarBackground

Comment: Could you explain more? When do you call these code lines? When searchBar is just allocated or when searchBar was showed on screen?

Comment: you are right indeed, i tried it in viewWillAppear and got textField . Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

I have created a recursive method which can work in any version of iOS

```
- (UITextField *) findTextFieldFromControl:(UIView *) view
{
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            return (UITextField *)subview;
        }
        else if ([subview.subviews count] > 0)
        {
            UIView *view = [self findTextFieldFromControl:subview];
            if (view) {
                return (UITextField *)view;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

you can call this method

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = [self findTextFieldFromControl:self.placeSearchBar];
```

Comment: Dint work for iOS 9 ... Probably Apple changed it again. Modified 
- (UITextField *) findTextFieldFromControl:(UIView *) view {
    int subViewIndex = 0;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        subViewIndex++;
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            return (UITextField *)subview;
        } else if (subViewIndex < view.subviews.count) {
            continue;
        } else if ([subview.subviews count] > 0) {
            subViewIndex = 0;
            return [self findTextFieldFromControl:subview];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the text field first.
Unfortunately the textfield is a private attribute.

You can loop and index the subviews to get the text field private attribute,
Or you can directly get the text field using the private attribute name.

Both way are same, you access the private attribute.

## 1. Loop

```
for subview in searchBar.subviews {
    for view in subview.subviews {
        if let searchField = view as? UITextField {
            // do something with the search field
        }
    } 
}
```

## 2. With key

```
let textField = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
let cancelBarButton = searchBar.valueForKey("cancelBarButtonItem") as? UIBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed answers use private key -and will be rejected by Apple- or use an `NSArray`and you cannot be sure this will persist in the future. If you want to change the color, attributes, etc of the text, use the appearanceWhenContainedIn:

```
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in order to get `UITextField` from `UISearchBar`:

```
    //First add the following macro:
    #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

    //- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    //Then get the text field object:
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        for (id object in [[[yourSearchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
        {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                NSLog(@"text field found");
                UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)object;
                //do some actions
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (id object in [yourSearchBar subviews])
        {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                NSLog(@"text field found");
                UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)object;
                //do some actions
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but problem here is that it does not go in If condition  if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) Condition as there is no such subview in the obtained array

Comment: @Bhumit I just tested it on iOS 7.1 and it's finding the text field. Have you put a log inside if statement?

Comment: Yes, already tried it here is the log
searchbar.subviews Array is (
    "<UISearchBarBackground: 0xe6bc9d0; frame = (0 0; 768 50); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xe6bcb20>>"
)

As you can see only 1 object

Comment: @Bhumit Actually starting from iOS 7 the only subview on a search bar is an UIView, which contains the text field. That is strange. Can you show code of your log?

Comment: Yes seems strange to me too, i have edited my question code for log is NSLog(@"searchbarview.subviews Array is %@",searchbarview.subviews.description);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `UITextField` of the `UISearchBar` use the following line of code:

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
```

hope this help! =)

Comment: The key is private and app could be rejected.